# Creating multi threads and instantiating runnable

Tags: java, oop, anonymous-class

This is a piece of code I am using as an example of how to run multiple threads:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ThreadDem {
    //field
    Runnable doRun;
    //constructor
    public ThreadDem(){
        //instantiates a runnable object
        doRun = new Runnable(){
            //have to override the abstract method run of runnable and am
                        //declaring method here in this block statement
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello from thread: " 
                                       + Thread.currentThread());
            }       
        };
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        ThreadDem demo = new ThreadDem();
        System.out.println("Hello this is from thread: " +
                     Thread.currentThread());
        //I use the invokelater method to invoke the run method of do run on a
                //seperate thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(demo.doRun);

    }
}
```

I more or less just took it from the docs on runnable. However I am finding it hard to understand why it works like this. I am still new to OOP and don't really understand how I can instantiate an interface(runnable) and if indeed my runnable object is not a class how can I define it a method(run())... can someone please explain to me in simple terms step by step exactly what is happening in that constructor so I can make sense of the process? Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have created is called an [Anonimous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). The link contains the official tutorial which explains what it is, but in a nutshell - you created a one-off class implementing `Runnable` and instantiated an object of said class.

As a suggestion - Don't try to tackle multithreading before you grasp the basic concepts of the language like OOP and grammar.

Comment: I see thanks. I mean the code is entirely understandable to me in what it is doing I simply could not work out how I was instantiating an object there without building a separate class so I'm very happy to put a name to what is going on - I will read over the link thanks :)

Comment: @user3651925 Creating a runnable to invoke with SwingUtilities is the multithreading analog of `System.out.println("Hello World!");`. Anyway, these tutorials explain quite a lot, including some aspects of multithreading. If you find them helpful, feel free to upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java interfaces can not be instantiated, they are simply guidelines of what a method must implement in order to implement that interface. In order to instantiate a thread in Java it's best to use

`public class ThreadDem extends Runnable` (recommended)

or

`public class ThreadDem extends Thread`.

At that point you're required to implement a "public void run" method that overwrites the empty one from Runnable. At that point you can simply call run on any object of type ThreadDem.